# How to set image width to take half the space in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android

I need a help on setting up ImageView width to take 50% of the space in the parent ConstraintLayout. Here is a part of the layout file that is responsible for image display:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster_iv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_margin_sides"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin_sides"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin_top_bottom"
            android:contentDescription="@string/iv_poster_description"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" /></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In the case above it takes all width available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use percentages to define the width and height (but only width in this case). Can you please add the following attributes to your ImageView

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
```

This should center your ImageView to take half of the space as you've requested.

Like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. I removed `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"` in my code as well